# How do I get a spatial value from EF Core's FromSqlRaw

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, linq, postgis

Recently I've encountered a problem where I just had to use FromSqlRaw to my db to execute the function of one of Postgresql extensions. This function returns a single entry, and I want to get value of this entry somehow. However, for some reasons I can't do it this way:

```
var buffer = DataContext.LayerDatas.FromSqlRaw($"select ST_Buffer(ld.\"Geom\", 100, 'join=mitre') " +
            $"from public.\"Layers\" ld where ld.\"LId\" = {layerId} and ld.\"OId\" = {objectId}").FirstOrDefault();
```

What's the propper way of getting calculated value from SqlRaw in order to use it in my code?

Edit:
When I execute query through DBeaver it gives me the following thing:
[image: Query result]

And I want to get this inside of my C# code.

But the code inside c# app gives me the following exception:

```
42601 syntax error (at or near "d"),
```

and it shows my query as:

```
{select ld."Geom", ST_Buffer(ld."Geom", 100, 'join=mitre') from public."Layers" ld where ld."LId" = f21e400c-9e6d-4c28-b14c-1f0ced5b6ebb and ld."OId" = 3126}
```

Comment: "I can't do it this way" => please specify: do you get a compile error? Exception? What message?

Comment: Which value?...

Comment: I get 42601 syntax error (at or near "d"), and it shows my query as: 

{select ld."Geom", ST_Buffer(ld."Geom", 100, 'join=mitre') from public."Layers" ld where ld."LId" = f21e400c-9e6d-4c28-b14c-1f0ced5b6ebb and ld."OId" = 3126}

Comment: Value of ST_Buffer(ld.\"Geom\", 100, 'join=mitre'), it's the functions that returns database entry st_buffer (MULTIPOLYGON(((Some coordinates))))

Comment: First, post the actual error text in the question itself.

Comment: The query is clearly invalid - the GUID value isn't quoted. This was caused because the query was created dynamically instead of using parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used string interpolation to generate the query string which resulted in an invalid query.

```
... where ld."LId" = f21e400c-9e6d-4c28-b14c-1f0ced5b6ebb
```

Instead of a parameterized query, the code created a SQL string with injected values that resulted in an invalid query.

[FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-3.1) works with normal strings and explicitly specified parameters. In fact, the docs [have a pretty big warning about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters).

**Using parameters with FromSqlRaw**

To use `FromSqlRaw`, interpolation must *not* be used. The parameters can be passed by position:

```
var sql="select ST_Buffer(ld.Geom, 100, 'join=mitre') 
from public.Layers ld 
where ld.LId = {0} and ld.OId = {1}";

var buffer = DataContext.LayerDatas.FromSqlInterpolated(sql,layerId,objectId)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

C# allows multiline strings so there's no need to use concatenation to make the query readable.

**Using interpolation with FromSqlInterpolated**

If you want to use interpolation to pass parameters you need [FromSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-3.1) :

```
var buffer = DataContext.LayerDatas.FromSqlInterpolated(
$"select ST_Buffer(ld.Geom, 100, 'join=mitre') 
from public.Layers ld 
where ld.LId = {layerId} and ld.OId = {objectId}"
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Notice that the string is *one long string* without concatenations. This produces the [FormattableString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=netcore-3.1) class expected by `FromSqlInterpolated`.

**Reading GIS types**

ST_Buffer is a standard GIS function used by [PostgreSQL](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-buffer) which returns a spatial type. In SQL Server it's [STBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stbuffer-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15).

Spatial types [are supported in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) through the [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) package and the database-specific packages mentioned in the docs.

For PostgreSQL the correct package is [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite). Its use is explained in [Spatial Mapping with NetTopologySuite](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nts.html)

To use it with EF Core, after installing the correct packages, it needs to be registered when configuring the DbContext, eg :

```
options.UseSqlServer(
    @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=WideWorldImporters",
    x => x.UseNetTopologySuite());
```

After that, spatial types and properties can be used the same as other types :

```
// Find the nearest city
var nearestCity = db.Cities
    .OrderBy(c => c.Location.Distance(currentLocation))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Well, not the case. I use the very same thing in another query and it works perfectly fine. LId is GUID, not the string, layerId is also of type GUID, so it works once again.

Comment: @Aldres It's exactly that. Look what the executed query looks like. You run a different query

Comment: @Aldres why don't you use FromSqlInterpolated *without* concatenations in the string? Or FromSqlRaw with explicit parameters?

Comment: Ah well, I forgot the quotes in once place, but this doesn't really answer my main question, my mistake, sorry and thank you!. So how do I gues this ST_Buffer thingy out of this query, If I don't have such a column in my LayerData entity?

Comment: @Aldres no amount of quoting is going to fix the vulnerabilities in dynamic SQL. The solution is to use parameterized queries. The error you posted was about the invalid query, not the `ST_Buffer` function

Comment: Yeah, thank you for that! I wasn't really aware of this. But is there a way to extract this ST_Buffer value from interpolated query?

Comment: @Aldres are you asking how to *read* that value? You need to add the proper spatial support package for your database. I describe how to do that

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Colossal thanks to you!